# Unable to run gulp task

Tags: gulp

I'm trying to run a simple `gulp-sass` task, but I'm getting this error:

```
[22:42:14] Starting 'sass'...
[22:42:14] Finished 'sass' after 10 ms

 events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
   Error: File not found with singular glob
at Glob.<anonymous> (D:\Development\WebStorm\calliope\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob-stream\index.js:34:30)
at Glob.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Glob._finish (D:\Development\WebStorm\calliope\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob-stream\node_modules\glob\glob.js:171:8)
at done (D:\Development\WebStorm\calliope\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob-stream\node_modules\glob\glob.js:158:12)
at Glob._processSimple2 (D:\Development\WebStorm\calliope\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob-stream\node_modules\glob\glob.js:640:12)
at D:\Development\WebStorm\calliope\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob-stream\node_modules\glob\glob.js:628:10
at Glob._stat2 (D:\Development\WebStorm\calliope\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob-stream\node_modules\glob\glob.js:724:12)
at lstatcb_ (D:\Development\WebStorm\calliope\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob-stream\node_modules\glob\glob.js:716:12)
at RES (D:\Development\WebStorm\calliope\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob-stream\node_modules\glob\node_modules\inflight\inflight.js:23:14)
at f (D:\Development\WebStorm\calliope\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob-stream\node_modules\glob\node_modules\once\once.js:17:25)
```

I Installed `gulp` both globally and locally as dev depency. 
Here's my task:

```
var gulp = require("gulp"),
sass = require("gulp-sass");

gulp.task("sass", function(){
    gulp.src('assets/sass/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css'))
});
```

Comment: This is weird, as it's hardly reproducible. How's your folder structure? Do those files exist? Are the relative to the Gulpfile's path?

Comment: My stupid mistake the path to `.scss` was wrong. What a mystic error by gulp :S

Comment: So it's a pathing error? I'm getting this error, and I'm suspecting it as well.

Comment: @ConAntonakos yes, it happens when the paths are not valid

Comment: @steo - Yeah; I confirmed that as well. Not a great error message, though. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is not so clear, by the way the `Exception` is throwed by a wrong link ( resource not found )

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct. The error is thrown whenever the resource is not found. I wrote a function to prevent such an occurrence in my files.
run "npm install fs --save".
then add this to your gulpfile

```
var fs = require('fs');
var validateResources = function (resources) {
  resources.forEach(function (resource) {
    if (!fs.existsSync(resource)) {
      throw resource + " not found!";
    }
  });
};
```

With this, you will be safe to some extent.